# Binding Data from Linq Entity Query to DataGrid WPF Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I can bind the data from query to my `datagrid` but I am encountering an issue when I want to format the `datagrid`, please forgive me if it is not clear:

I have a class to hold the list of value so I do not need to do the conversion from `C# Anonymous Type` in order to use query

```
    public class SoftwareSummaryModel
{
    public string Software { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfUser { get; set; }

}
```

When the program is initialized, I would like to load the default data to `dgSummary`

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (var context = new QuotingEntities(BuildConnectionString()))
        {
            var query = from p in context.SoftwareTrackings
                        group p by p.Software into g
                        select new SoftwareSummaryModel
                        {
                            Software = g.Key,
                            NumberOfUser = g.Count()
                        };

            dgSummary.ItemsSource = query.ToList();

        }
    }
```

Then it is fine, datagrid `dgSummary` displays 2 columns `Software` and `NumberOfUser`.  Now, I would like to fix the width of the 2 columns (and I will do some formatting):

```
<DataGrid Name="dgSummary" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="2" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="160" Binding="{Binding Software}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="160" Binding="{Binding NumberOfUser}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `dgSummary` display 2 formatted columns and 2 none formatted columns of `Software` and `NumberOfUser` ~~~~> Total 4 columns while I expect to have only 2.

Comment: You want each column displayed twice? I'm confused as to why you have `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` and you are also explicitly defining the columns...

Comment: @ Ron Beyer, ah - `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, my problem is fixed - stupid me.  Initial I did not put the `AutoGenerateColumns` and I thought the default value is `false` but I guess if I do not put `AutoGenerateColumns`, the default value is `true`